# Can I use the CTools modal functionality under HTTPS adn Display Suite?

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite, display-suite, javascript, ssl

The client for a new project wants their content to display in a modal overlay.  From my research so far, it seems using ctools is the way to go.

My question is, some of this content will be product displays (using Drupal Commerce).  Will there be a conflict with the AJAX functionality while the pages are HTTPS?  I'm also using Display Suite to lay out the content.  Is anyone familiar with any issues that may arise while using ctools' modal functionality with Display Suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS should just work, or I would say there's a bug in ctools.

I haven't used DS much, so can't really comment, but DS handles View modes, and I would expect all ctools modules to deal nicely with those.